# Issue with POST

Tags: php, mysql, post

I'm quite new with PHP and I can't figure one thing out, and I bet there's quite a simple solution to it.

The thing is, on one page I have multiple rows that show `Product ID`.
I'm trying to remove the selected row by retrieving the post `$product_id = $_POST['pid'];` on a different .php, however the value I get returned is the last row it posted and not the selected row, this is causing me to remove the last row when trying to remove the first row for example.

What do I need to change in order for me to get the **Selected** POST `product_id` and not the last posted one?

As I said I'm quite new so I'm sure there are some errors in my code or its way too simple anyway here's what I'm trying to do.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * from shoppingcart_items WHERE shoppingcart_id=".$wid."";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2, $con) or die('sql2'.mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))                       
$pid = $row['product_id'];                                     
echo '<td><input type="text" name="pid"  value="'. $pid .'"></td> ';
```

And this retrieves rows like 3,4,5,7 etc.  and on the other php page I try to delete the selected row.

```
$sql2 ="DELETE FROM shoppingcart_items WHERE product_id = '".$_REQUEST["pid"]."' AND shoppingcart_id ='".$_REQUEST["wid"]."'";
```

So what happens is I deleted the last value which is 7 and not the one I selected for example 3.

Comment: This would be much easier to debug if we could see some code.

Comment: We'll need to see some code to be able to help you.

Comment: Please show some of the HTML and PHP code, however I am guessing you are using the same name in your html instead of an array so <input name="foo"> instead of <input name="foo[]">?

Comment: added some code i hope it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

1. Use some developer tools in your browser to verify that the correct POST data is being sent to the PHP script. I REALLY (REALLY, REALLY, REALLY) enjoy Chrome's developer tools. You can watch all network traffic and then get detailed information on it. There are a bunch of developer tool kits that are great though.
2. `echo` the query you're attempting to run in PHP to check that's it is correct.

Just a couple general things to do whenever debugging web applications.

Bonus - Always make sure to escape data or cast it as an integer (in the case of IDs) to make sure you can't be attacked by SQL injection.

E.g.

```
$querySTR = 'SELECT * FROM sensitive_data WHERE id=' . (integer)$_POST['id'] . " AND username='" . $db->real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "'";
```

Note that this is using PHP's mysqli extension and `$db` is a valid database connection resource.

Oh, and nobody can give specific help unless you post specific code :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're assigning the same 'input' name for each possible product id in your foreach (being 'name="pid"'), so you'll end up with multiple same names...

Would be the same like saying:
'Apple is green'
'Apple is red'
'Apple is black'

Which colour does the apple has ?

Comment: Thanks for telling me what my issue is i had no clue.. sigh

Comment: The last value will actually be sent to the server.

Comment: exactly and thats what i want i dont want it to get the last value